# Mac OS X 10.9.5, Spotlight and pCloud

Tags: macos, indexing, spotlight, pcloud

I have a pCloud drive mounted under /Users/me/pCloud Drive. Some of the folders are locally synced under /Users/me/pCloud Local. There are several PDF files that have been OCR'ed and they are perfectly indexed if I save them in e.g. /Users/me/Downloads but unfortunately not when I save in any of the two pCloud folders.

I have rebuilt the Spotlight index on /Volumes/Macintosh HD with no luck.

Those folders do NOT appear in the privacy tab of Spotlight (i.e. they are not excluded from indexing).

Any idea welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight does not seem to index the fuse-mounted pCloud drive.  The support team says they are working on it with Apple.  Case closed for that part.

For the PDF files saved on the APFS (Apple's native file system), the problem does not come from the indexing but from the following fact : I OCR files using Acrobat Reader under Windows 7 and save them to APFS.  Some of the original files already contain hidden text (thus created by the creator of the PDF) and in some cases, the text is somehow not recognised by Spotlight.  What is strange is that :
- if I open the file with Acrobat Reader under Mac OS, I can copy and paste the text
- if I open the same file with Preview.app, I can select the text, copy it but what I paste is blank text (or empty, I am not sure).

I haven't found the reason yet...